# Find a value in set of other values

Tags: php, mysql

If I have a single value and I want to see if it is in a set of values in a particular table cell, know I can use FIND_IN_SET

```
$myStr = 'b';

// myVals column contains 'a,b,c,d'

mysql> SELECT FIND_IN_SET(".$myStr.", myVals);
    -> 2
```

But what if I have a string of values that I need to check if either of them is in the  SET?

```
$myStr = 'f,g,b,d';
```

Is there a way to do it in the query directly or do I need to run some loop with PHP?

Comment: I can't test it now but try: `SELECT FIND_IN_SET((SELECT 'f','g','b','d'), 'a,b,c,d')`

Comment: How about `$sql = "select find_in_set('b','" . $myStr . "');";`.

Comment: @ott sometimes that string can only contain a single value, without a comma

Comment: What's wrong with a set containing only one element?

Comment: @ott, I think we're talking about different things. I've updated original port to clarify.

Comment: You'll have to split value and create `OR`s with `IN`s. MySQL doesn't have an intersect function to match 2 lists.

Comment: @Rudie, so it's a combo of PHP/MySQL approach? So it'll be something like WHERE ('f' IN myVals OR 'g' IN myVals...) ?

Comment: @santa Yes, see answer. `FIND_IN_SET` still works though. May be simpler than `IN`. No idea about perf.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your query's sequence is incorrect.

You're using `FIND_IN_SET(".$myStr.", myVals)` where it should be the other way around.

```
FIND_IN_SET(myVals, ".$myStr.")
```

- *column, string to search*

You can use the following in conjunction with `mysqli_num_rows()`.

Sidenote: `column_x` would be the column you wish to query.

Assuming a `mysqli_` database connection library:

```
$myStr = 'f,g,b,d';

$query = mysqli_query($connection, "

    SELECT column_x FROM table 
    WHERE FIND_IN_SET(column_x, '".$myStr."')

 ");

$num_row = mysqli_num_rows($query);

    if($num_row >0)
        {
           echo "It exists.";
        } 

        else
        {
           echo "It does not exist.";
        }
```

---

References:

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set
- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Comment: Yep, was getting ready to come back to this @Fred -ii- only to find that you've nailed it on the head. *Morning Ralph!*

Comment: @JayBlanchard - *Ah,* I didn't know you were going to come back to it, as I noticed your answer was still deleted at the time of my answer. Let's hope that's what the OP wants to achieve. *Mornin' Sam!*

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to make `OR`s that check `IN`s or `FIND_IN_SET`s. The result for `$myStr = 'f,g,b,d'` would be:

```
SELECT (
  FIND_IN_SET('f', 'a,b,c,d') OR
  FIND_IN_SET('g', 'a,b,c,d') OR
  FIND_IN_SET('b', 'a,b,c,d') OR
  FIND_IN_SET('d', 'a,b,c,d')
)
```

That should be easy to make in PHP and it will still be 1 query.

It won't return any index though. Just a bool. If you need the first matching index, you need a massive IF or CASE.

Comment: Oh, I just need to know if it's there or not. No need for index.

Comment: I'm curious about the exact use case though. I can't imagine you're not querying a table. If you are querying a table, a JOIN might be better suited...

Comment: I store some values in a cookie and then need to compare against the records in db.

Answer (score -1):

[MySQL Regexp](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html) is definitely one way to accomplish your goal.